# Neo4j, cypher - how to return node degree in its properties?

Tags: neo4j, cypher

What I am using now is this query:

```
MATCH (Parent)-[R]-(Child) WHERE ID(Parent)=$parentId
CALL {
    WITH Child
    RETURN apoc.node.degree(Child) as ChildDegree
}
RETURN Parent, Child, R, ChildDegree
LIMIT $limit
```

Current solution works great but I am currently rebuilding our backend and I was wondering if it is possible to just "inject" node degree into all of the nodes' properties somehow?

By properties I mean this object:

[image]

This would simplify backend a lot as I am using this degree counting in every query.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok so you can merge your node with an object containing its degree using:

```
MATCH (Parent)-[R]-(Child) WHERE ID(Parent)=268
RETURN Parent, apoc.map.merge(Child, {degree: apoc.node.degree(Child)}) as Child, R
LIMIT 100
```

Answer (score 0):

You can return a map projection with its degree added :

```
MATCH (Parent)-[R]-(Child) WHERE ID(Parent)=268
RETURN Parent, Child{.*, degree: apoc.node.degree(Child) } as Child, R
LIMIT 100
```